# Issues reading .mdb files in R

Tags: r, ms-access, database-connection, hmisc

I'm trying to read a series of microsoft access databases in R. I found the *mdb.get* function from the *Hmisc* package which uses *mdb-tools*.

This is my workflow for one particular .mdb file

```
system("wget http://www.dgis.salud.gob.mx/descargas/zip/BDSS_2004.zip")
unzip("BDSS_2004.zip")
mdb.get("SECTORIAL2004.mdb")
   Can't alloc filename
   Couldn't open database.
   named list()
   Warning message:
   running command 'mdb-tables -1 SECTORIAL2004.mdb' had status 1
```

I've tried passing the commando directly using *System()* to give the *mdb-tables* command but I get very similar results.

```
system("mdb-tables SECTORIAL2004.mdb")   
   Can't alloc filename
   Couldn't open database.
```

The main issue is that when I do it directly in the terminal it works fine for the same files. I guess I could do it using a shell script but I rather do it inside R. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've neglected to say that I'm running this code in RStudio, I've tried running it in the R Terminal alone and it works so that makes me think it has something to do with the filepath to *mdb-tools* or something like that. That being said, I still would prefer to be able to do this in RStudio. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

... I tried to reproduce your error but everything works fine for me.

Judging from the error message ("Can't alloc filename") and what you are saying ("a **series** of microsoft access databases"), I would bet that you are hitting the memory limits of what R can handle.

Here are a couple of advices that could help you:

1. You may be able to free some useless stuff with `rm`. Run `gc()` to trigger the garbage collector before loading the file, so you are assured that all the free memory will be available. This may be enough to solve your problem.
2. If this is not enough: import sequentially the **mdb** files, one at a time, saving each of them in your hard drive in another format (like the default `.RData`) and clearing completely your workspace. You will still probably need to worry about space when you will open them later, to do analyses with them, but at least you won't have to go through the *mdb* -> *R* conversion step.
3. Finally, do you *really* need R for reading that database? If not, you would save a lot of troubles just by using other technologies (python?) to read your database.

Finally, one generic advice to handle a lot of data: you should really consider to learn how to use `data.tables` in case you don't know about it already.

Comment: Hello, thnx for the reply. I don't think my problem is size, I can even read a small .mdb on R but I can read it in the terminal without a hitch.
I was trying to read this using RStudio and I think that is the problem because I can read all the .mdbs if I run the same code in R but in the terminal.

Comment: @eclark: Could you try to execute the *same* script in R (terminal version) or in Rstudio? My bet is that they will likely have the same problem.

Comment: @eclark: Otherwise, without a reproducible example we just can't help you!

Comment: Ok, I've tried executing it on R(terminal Version) and it works without a problem, the problem arises when I run it in RStudio.

Comment: ... and it works for me in Rstudio (latest version, linux). It would be great if you could file a bug report to the rstudio team.

Comment: I've reinstalled RStudio and it works now. I don't know what was going on. But thanks for the help!!